# позиционирование в bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap

Начал изучать bootstrap и возник вопрос, при медиа запросах в css можно было позиционировать элемент на странице как угодно для каждого разрешения, ручками. в bootstrap я указывают к примеру `col-xs-6` на некоторые элементы `hidden-xs`, но не пойму как их двигать, ведь если буду двигать класс то он будет двигаться и в других разрешениях `lg` `md`

Comment: пожалуйста пишите более развернутые вопросы. приведите пример кода(или ваш оригинальный код), чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему.

Comment: приходится гадать ! но смотрите к примеру вы хотите двигать элемент при разрешении экрана @media screen and (max-width:768px) and (min-width:...) то в css ищите эту связку

Comment: спасибо за комментарии, согласен с вами, нужно было конкретизировать вопрос. 
код не отправлю т.к. это более абстрактный вопрос. ну вот я насколько понял двигать при разных разрешениях по горизонтали я могу с помощью отступов offset и меняя кол-во столбцов. а вот по вертикали, я как вариант задаю еще один row (пустой) и задаю в css height скрываю на md lg  а на xs xm задаю display-block. но это как-то извращенно

Answer (score 2):

Ну, для начала, предположу, что двигать надо горизонтально и отвечу на вопрос. `col-xs-offset-3` сдвинет блок только на три позиции и только в расширении `xs`, но при этом вы так же должны указать для других расширений свои значения, например, чтобы оставить блок на месте в `sm` пишем `col-sm-offset-0`, тогда и в более крупных разрешениях мы будем иметь смещение 0.

Comment: Спасибо коллега, а то что-то с телефона не получилось сделать нормальное форматирование